# Is past life real?

Tags: life, spirituality

Is past life talked about by various spiritual gurus true or it's a scam..
?
Do people who are alive now really lived some time back...and took birth again

Comment: have you ever wondered what happens after death, or before birth ?

Comment: What is the main difference between an alive & dead person? Its soul.You will say a body dies because of failure of organ as soul cant be seen flying out from a dead body by masses. You have to understand that word 'spirituality' itself means understanding/realizing the spirit/soul and God is not so easy to reveal its secret to every undeserving being. Just like animals have no religion or God, similarly next spiritual evolution is understanding of immortal spirit/soul unlike teachings of fake kaliyuga babas. Ghosts, Devas, Apsaras, they are all spirits and cant be seen by masses or animals.

Comment: Past life is real as per Hindu scriptures, Hinduism. Are you looking for some other kjnd of evidences?

Comment: is current life real? if so, then past was real. Upanishads claim current life is unreal and Atman is real. So, in that case past life is unreal. In atman's perspective, present, past and future is unreal. Hence, the immortal/timelessness for Atman and mortality of life. In Parabrahman's - when it has 3 attributes 1) it's lone awareness 2) real atman 3) lives + world of atman -  unique perspective, everything is surreal real atman and unreal life that atman lives in body etc. and that's like seeing his own body structure. imagine you are looking inside your body and you cannot look outside.

Comment: Are you looking for scientific proof or scriptural support?

Answer (score 3):

> Is past life real?

Yes.

From the [Bhagavad Gita](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/2/):

> TEXT 20: For the soul there is neither birth nor death at any time. He
> has not come into being, does not come into being, and will not come
> into being. He is unborn, eternal, ever-existing and primeval. He is
> not slain when the body is slain.
>
> TEXT 22: As a person puts on new garments, giving up old ones, the
> soul similarly accepts new material bodies, giving up the old and
> useless ones.

Comment: One of my friend gave me an argument which confused me..if past life is real...then everyone living today had a past life...and so the population today is 7.8 billion....if past life way real than by that logic 100 years back or even 1000 years back these people would have been there....so the population 100 year back and 1000 year back would have been 7.8 billion...which is not th case...so how can there be a past life for an individual person

Comment: @Ronitsharma The Hindu universe is much bigger than just our planet Earth. They could have come from elsewhere.

Comment: @ronitsharma hence the promotion of species from worms to humans. Certainly you could find 7.8 billion worms and other life form before humans . Sama Veda says that the job of devas is to promote your body from that of an earthworm to human. So being human is a privilege. And yes your great...great...... grandfather was an earthworm 

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [Ikshvaku's perfect answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/42899/3294):

Here there is mention that we have different births, although there is a distinction between us (living entities or in sanskrit *atma*) and the supreme being (the super soul or in sanskrit *paramatma*).

[TEXT 4:](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/4/) Arjuna said: The sun-god Vivasvān is senior by birth to You. How am I to understand that in the beginning You instructed this science to him?

[TEXT 5:](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/5/) The Personality of Godhead said: Many, many births both you and I have passed. I can remember all of them, but you cannot, O subduer of the enemy!

Here further to the origin and nature of the (living entitiy or in sanskrit *atma*) and how they get entangled in the (material energy or in sanskrit *prakrit*) basically while interacting with *prakrit* they (*atma*) [create what we call their *nature*](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/3/33/) and later this very same *nature* pushes them to action (through desires, fears, conceptions etc)

more details here:

[TEXT 8:](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/15/8/) The living entity in the material world carries his different conceptions of life from one body to another, as the air carries aromas. Thus he takes one kind of body and again quits it to take another.

[TEXT 9:](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/15/9/) The living entity, thus taking another gross body, obtains a certain type of ear, eye, tongue, nose and sense of touch, which are grouped about the mind. He thus enjoys a particular set of sense objects.

[TEXT 10:](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/15/10/) The foolish cannot understand how a living entity can quit his body, nor can they understand what sort of body he enjoys under the spell of the modes of nature. But one whose eyes are trained in knowledge can see all this.